# Redis Server doesn't start or do anything - Redis-64 on Windows

Tags: redis, nosql

I'm following these steps outlines on this link, however when I try to start the server nothing happens nor can I connect to anything from the client.  Does anyone know how to run this?

when I try from a command prompt instead of double clicking the redis-server.exe I get this message

[11868] 23 Jul 11:58:26.325 # QForkMasterInit: system error caught. error code=0
x000005af, message=VirtualAllocEx failed.: unknown error

http://bartwullems.blogspot.ca/2013/07/unofficial-redis-for-windows.html

> The easiest way to install Redis is through NuGet:
>
> ```
> Open Visual Studio
> Create an empty solution so that NuGet knows where to put the packages
> Go the Package Manager Console: Tools –> Library Package Manager –>Package Manager Console
> Type Install-Package Redis-64
> ```
>
> image
>
> ```
> Go to the Packages folder and browse to the Tools folder. Here you’ll find the Redis-server.exe. Double click on it to start it.
> ```
>
> Redis is ready to use and start’s listening on a specific port(6379 in
>   my case)
>
> image
>
> ```
> Let’s open up a client and try to put a value into Redis. Start Redis-cli.exe. It already connects to the same port by default.
> ```
>
> image
>
> ```
> Add a value by executing following command:
> ```
>
> image
>
> ```
> Read the value again:
> ```
>
> image

Answer (score 1):

Try to run with redis-server --maxheap 4000000

Answer (score 0):

Miguel is correct, but it is not that simple. To start redis-server either as a service or from the command prompt, the amount of available RAM and disk space must be sufficient for Redis to run as configured.

Now, if no configuration file is specified when running Redis, it will use the default configuration values. All of this is documented in the redis.windows.conf file as well as in the document "Redis on Windows.docx" (both deployed with the redis installation).

In my experience, errors when starting Redis usually come from lack of available resources (RAM or disk space) or some incorrect configuration of maxhead or maxmemory parameters.

To troubleshoot this kind of behavior, check your system's available resources and try running redis-server from the command line varying the parameters maxmemory, maxheap, and/or heapdir. The loglevel parameter set to verbose might also help diagnosing the issue.

Regards